# After creating an executable ShinyApp when Rendering Rmarkdown Stops in R

Tags: r

I have a shiny app where in the server.R I have the following code to generate a .html file from Markdown (.rmd) file:

```
rmarkdown::render("report.rmd", output_file ="www/report.html", output_format = "html_document", quiet = TRUE)
```

And this is the markdown file *report.rmd* header:

````
---
title: "REPORT OF DC"
date: "This report will introduce you a report of the file for analyzing"
output: html_document

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache=FALSE)
```
````

And if I want to visualize the generated file I have this piece of code in UI.R:

```
shiny::actionButton(inputId='ab3', label="Report", 
                                  icon = icon("th"), 
                                  onclick ="window.open('report.html', '_blank')")
```

So executing my app through RStudio works fine but when I generate an executable using RInno library as follows the option to generate HTML it doesn't work.

```
require(RInno)

RInno::install_inno()

create_app(app_name = "App", 
           app_dir = "C:/Users/...", 
           include_R = TRUE, 
           R_version = "3.4.0",
           pkgs=c("shiny","shinydashboard","knitr", "data.table", "tools", "stringr", 
                  "lubridate", "readxl","DT","markdown","rmarkdown","xtable",
                  "htmltools","devtools","shinyjs","RMySQL"),
           remotes     = c("jbkunst/highcharter") # GitHub packages
 )
compile_iss()
```

Comment: Maybe you have to set the path to pandoc. I would try `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="path/to/pandoc")` e.g. in `global.R`.

Comment: ... or try the option `include_Pandoc = TRUE` in `create_app`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Stéphane Laurent comments I came to this solution:

First of all, I checked if I had pandoc installed executing this in R:

```
pandoc.location <- Sys.which("pandoc")
if(pandoc.location == ""){
    print("pandoc not available")
}else{
    print("pandoc available")
}
```

I realized it wasn't installed so I had to install it executing the following code:

```
# installing/loading the package:
if(!require(installr)) { install.packages("installr"); require(installr)} #load/ install+load installr

# Installing pandoc
install.pandoc()
```

Finally, I changed my function creat_app adding `include_Pandoc = TRUE`:

```
create_app(app_name = "App", 
           app_dir = "C:/Users/...",
           include_Pandoc = TRUE,
           include_R = TRUE, 
           R_version = "3.4.0",
           pkgs=c("shiny","shinydashboard","knitr", "data.table", "tools", "stringr", 
                  "lubridate", "readxl","DT","markdown","rmarkdown","xtable",
                  "htmltools","devtools","shinyjs","RMySQL"),
           remotes     = c("jbkunst/highcharter") # GitHub packages
 )
```

And that's all it's working perfectly!